# Java hash function in bash

Tags: java, bash

I'm trying to make a bash script which generates the same hash code like this java hash function:

```
import java.security.Security;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public final static String hash(final String _password)
      throws Exception
   {
      String _salt="0c321e8669fce545";
      Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
      final String algorithm = "SHA-256";
      final String encoding = "UTF-8";
         MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
         md.reset();
         md.update(_salt);
         byte[] digest = md.digest(_password.getBytes(encoding));
         char[] hashChars = Hex.encodeHex(digest);
         return salt + new String(hashChars);
      }
```

E.g. I tried it with a static salt and the ssl method to create the password hash:

```
#!/bin/bash
salt='0c321e8669fce545'
passwordHash=$(echo -n 'hello' | openssl sha256)
finalPassword=$(echo $salt$passwordHash)
```

But I never get the same result.
Is there any way to realize this?

Edit: My goal is to create a password which is accepted by a platform using this java function for it's password creation.

Comment: Please post your bash script as well

Comment: I added it to my post.

Comment: You're ignoring the salt when calculating the sha256-hash in bash

Comment: Thanks. How can I implement this seed in the hash calculation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `-salt` and `-pass` parm. On CentOS, I do something like this in bash:

```
############################################
# To be used with the -pass parm of openssl
# It's the salt for creating hash
############################################
export enc_salt="0c321e8669fce545"

encyption_file="/tmp/encrypted_pwd.enc"

echo -n 'hello' | openssl aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -a -salt -pass env:enc_salt -out $encyption_file

# Decrypt

openssl aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -d -a -salt -pass env:enc_salt -in $encyption_file
```

Since each time you run this, even with the same salt, it will give you a different hash.  I doubt it will ever match what you are seeing in your Java program.  What's important is when you de-crypt the encryption in `bash` or `Java`, it should give you what you are looking for.

The reason for using an environment variable for the salt is so anyone lurking using `ps` command monitoring what is executing will not see the salt passed to `openssl`

On a `64 bit OS`, substitute `-base64` for `-a` parm when using `openssl`

Comment: Thanks the command is working fine. But it seems not to create the same password design like the java function because I can't use the generated password for the login.